# Limits and Breaks

Tags: r, limit, break

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvBeE.png)

For this question, I have been able to split the data into two histograms with one being income above the median and the other being income below median. The following code is what I've done so far:

```
library(openintro)
data("countyComplete")
attach("countyComplete")

median(median_household_income, na.rm = FALSE)

x<-subset(countyComplete,median_household_income > 42445)
y<-subset(countyComplete,median_household_income < 42445)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x$median_household_income, main="Income Above Median" )
hist(y$median_household_income,main = "Income Below Median")
```

However, I am a bit confused about how do I force histograms to use same limits on y axis, as well as breaks. Could someone point me in the right direction. I tried to do this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x$median_household_income,
     breaks=seq(0,100,by=5),
     freq = FALSE,
     ylim=c(0,.15),
     xlim = range(breaks),
     main="Income Above Median")
hist(y$median_household_income, main = "Income Below Median")
```

But I only get one histogram showing up on my plot screen and the console says 
 "Error in hist.default(x$median_household_income, breaks = seq(0, 100,  : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'".

What do I do?

Comment: If you want to continue using base graphics `hist`, set `axes = FALSE` and then use the `axis()` command after creating `hist` to add the axes individually exactly as you want them. Otherwise, switch to `ggplot`.

Comment: As a side note, I'd strongly recommend never using `attach`. You're already using functions like `subset` that can evaluate unquoted column names. Using `attach` is a risky convenience, often leading to bugs where your attached columns get out of sync with each other and with the source data.

Answer (score 0):

I would forget the `breaks` argument. It doesn't make sense, you are plotting values below and above the median, they do not intersect.

As for the histograms, I have precomputed the median, and the maximum value of the density.

```
library(openintro)
data("countyComplete")

med <- median(countyComplete$median_household_income, na.rm = FALSE)

x <- subset(countyComplete, median_household_income > med)
y <- subset(countyComplete, median_household_income < med)

hx <- hist(x$median_household_income, plot = FALSE)
hy <- hist(y$median_household_income, plot = FALSE)
MaxY <- max(c(hx$density, hy$density))

op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(x$median_household_income, main = "Income Above Median",
     freq = FALSE, ylim = c(0, MaxY))
hist(y$median_household_income, main = "Income Below Median",
     freq = FALSE, ylim = c(0, MaxY))
par(op)
```